How to pass different values (value types) through function parameters?
GCC compiler is giving me the following message:
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘Collection.add’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   93 |     Collection.add(coll, 2500);
      |                          ^~~~
      |                          |
      |                          int
note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’

First: I understand what it's telling me and I just wanted to see what it would do when I passed an int where a void* is expected. I can ... mmmm ... kind of live with the warning, but it's not something I feel should be in a polished library for public release.
Second: I could use the -Wint-conversion option to disable the warning. But what if we want a warning if someone does this on another function call where the developer should receive a warning - ex. for some potentially undefined results?
I could write another method that accepts int values. But then I have to write a value for every other primitive ... and then comes char* with it's own add function.
Is there a solution to resolve the warning in the code rather than lazily telling the compiler to ignore such warnings?

I submit that code characterized as "I just wanted to see what it would do" does not belong in a published release whether it yields warnings or not.

As for what to write instead, that depends on what you are trying to achieve.  Note well that C does not have an "Any" type.  A void * is safely and implicitly interconvertible with all other object pointer types, but that's not the same thing.

You could maybe use a variadic argument (i.e. use a printf style argument), but you would need another argument which specifies the type of the argument (as is the case with printf).

Isn't this C++? Collection.add isn't valid C.

@Alexander: It is valid C if add is a function pointer in a struct.

@AndreasWenzel Ahhh, true.

IAbstract, "Is there a solution" --> consider using generic to steer code to the matching function.

@JohnBollinger ... the warning vibes from a unit test ... something another development might try. So what I'm asking is how to improve the interface.

@AndreasWenzel: That's exactly what it is.

void * is fine if you want to store values that are pointers to objects.  This can serve any data type in the sense that you can always insert a level of indirection between the collection and the ultimate subject.  But if you want to store non-pointer values without indirection then you should have appropriate types.  You could consider fewer than all the built-in types, however.  For instance, long long int could suffice for all signed integer types, and long double for all real floating types.

Just to illustrate _Generic (*) with your example
// define addint(), adddouble(), addstring(), etc

#define COLLADD(x, y) _Generic((y),              \
                               int: addint,      \
                               double: addouble, \
                               char*: addstring, \
                               default: add      \
                               )((x), (y))

COLLADD(coll, 2500);
COLLADD(coll, 3.14159);
COLLADD(coll, "foo");
COLLADD(coll, NULL);

(*) Standardized with C11

Since nobody so far addressed the elephant in the room:
The compiler warning comes from the code being invalid C - it is a so-called constraint violation of the language. You cannot convert between pointers and integers without a cast. "Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues
And that's the wrong solution anyway - the code does not do what you seem to think it does. It does not pass the integer 2500 to the function, it passes the address 2500 to the function and tells it to go fetch whatever hidden treasure that resides at that address. Addresses are normally written with hex notation so that would be 0x9C4... probably not a correct address on most computers.
For the case when you do want to convert an absolute address to a pointer, you are most likely dealing with very low-level code accessing hardware directly, in which case you should be using volatile qualified pointers. See How to access a hardware register from firmware?
To write a type-generic function with void*, which seems to be what you actually want to do, there needs to be some handling of that both on the function side and the caller side. Normally in old time C, one would create some manner of struct/union and mark the type in an enum variable. In modern C there are safer and better alternatives with _Generic etc as seen in another answer.
Yet another solution would be to pass along a function pointer callback, which is handling the type-specific part - see for example how the C standard library does this with the bsearch function.

And please note that a warning does not often mean "here's a little cosmetic hiccup you can fix a rainy day" but very often means "here's a fat bug which will cause your program to go haywire". In this case for example you are doing something as severe as violating C language constraints and still "just a warning" is sufficient diagnostics, as far as the C standard is concerned - What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?


Is there a solution to resolve the warning in the code rather than lazily telling the compiler to ignore such warnings?

Yes, convert the value to the destination value.
Collection.add(coll, (void*)2500);


Just a warning, you'll need to be careful that you don't try to dereference it later, since the void * isn't a reference to an int, it itself holds the value of the int.

KamilCuk, In general, an integer converted to a void * and then attempted recovery back to that integer type is not specified by C to result in the same value.

... but the OP should note that this comes with caveats.  Specifically: the resulting pointer value might not be properly aligned and / or might be a trap representation (though it probably isn't); the result of this conversion and the reverse conversion are implementation-defined, and the two are not necessarily inverses of each other (though they usually are); and the behavior of the reverse conversion is undefined under some circumstances.  Overall, even if none of that bites you, using a pointer to convey an integer value is poor style.

You could use (void*)(uintptr_t)2500

@JohnBollinger: excellent point. I'll use it if you don't mind to help explain why it's not a good idea to do it.

@IAbstract, because pointers are in a completely different type category from integers, notwithstanding that it is permitted to convert between these.  Using a pointer value to convey an integer is misleading. Also because even if the issues I describe don't bite you, in your development environment, they might well bite someone else who tries to deploy your code in a different environment. And because it conflicts with MISRA C and a variety of other popular sets of style guidelines, some backed by automated conformance checkers, with which your code might (eventually) need to comply.

What you can try to dynamically allocate memory for the integer and passing a pointer to the integer
int *data = malloc(sizeof(int));
*data = 2500;
    
if (data == NULL) {
    perror("Memory allocation failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

Collection.add(coll, data);

free(data);

